# import vs importance

Tags: word-choice, difference

> **[import](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/import)** {noun}:
>
> 1. *(usually imports)* A commodity, article, or service brought in from abroad for sale:
>
> 2. *[in singular]* The implicit meaning or significance of something

How do '**importance**' and *definition 2* of '**import**' differ? I ask not about definition 1 above that '**importance**' lacks.

Answer (score 2):

*Import* is rarely used to mean "significance" outside of formal/academic writing.  *Importance* is used for this purpose in nearly all cases.

This isn't simply a difference between casual conversation and formal writing.  I'm a reasonably well spoken and well read native speaker of American English who is not afraid of using my vocabulary, and I would be surprised if I had ever used that meaning in conversation before. *Importance* is far more common, probably even in formal and academic writing. In modern writing, *import* seems to be used as a way of making writing sound more sophisticated or in fiction, to make a character seem pompous.

Answer (score 1):

"importance" is the normal word. In elevated or literary style you can find 
"import"(stress on the first syllable): Yes, it is a matter of 'import.
(I have read it only once in a SF-novel.)

Comment: How's 'importance' more normal than 'import'? Sci Fi's use of language may differ?

Answer (score 0):

"Importance" is the widely accepted word for something of significant meaning as "import" is usually associated with the bringing in of goods. However, both are perfectly alright to use.

Comment: Sorry, but it’s unclear to me how this answers my question. I already confirmed my knowledge that `"import" is usually associated with the bringing in of goods. `

Answer (score 0):

I have heard  people use  import  in  scientific conferences like 'what is the scientific import of your observations'? In this case it means significance

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a formal e-mail where I said:

> "please feel free to disclose anything of import".

Personally, I think **"import"** sounded better melodically- it was a purely stylistic choice. I think in terms of *meaning*, however, both **"of importance"** and **"of import"** are exactly the same. So pick the one that flows best in the sentence you are writing!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not a native speaker but from personal experience the word "**import**" is most often used in the meaning "*A commodity, article, or service brought in from abroad for sale*" and less often used in the meaning "*The implicit meaning or significance of something*".

As synonyms "**import**" and "**importance**" aren't quite interchangeable but share common meanings. The word "**import**" carries more than is given by the definition you refer to. From practice, the word "**import**" implies several definitions *(especially '**of import**')*:

- intended to bring significant value
- has important effects or influence
- a meaning that is not expressly stated but can be inferred

Thus knowing this we can understand the following examples as:

1. He's the **guy of import** in the company. - *He's the one who brings significant value or (and) exerts his influence in the company*
2. **Nothing of import**, My Lord. - *Nothing significant*
3. **A quick import of his speech** was ready in ten minutes. - *An implication of his speech: the meaning that is not expressly stated but can be inferred*
4. **The raise of import of the company** in the area comes from its employees. - *The company gets its influence raise in the area from the good work of its employees.*